# Is this notation mathematically-correct? $\cot\alpha\pm\tan\alpha=\frac2{{\sin\atop\tan}(2\alpha)}$

Tags: trigonometry, notation

I have a question.
Look at the following expression:

> $$\cot\alpha\pm\tan\alpha=\frac2{{\sin\atop\tan}(2\alpha)}$$

Is it written well, according to the laws of mathematical language?

In that formula, I meant that in case of '$+$' we will use the $\sin()$ function, and in case of '$-$' we will use the $\cos()$ function.

If it's not good, is there a good way (a mathematically-correct way) of writing both cases (both '$+$' and '$-$') in one formula?

by the way,
do you think that this **general explanatory** is good and **understandable**?

> $a \pm b = {func1\atop func2}(c)$

means:

> $a+b=func1(c)$
>
> $a-b=func2(c)$

Thank you,
Tom

Comment: I don't see anything in the link.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I have seen a construction like this before, but you might want to put in explanatory text along the lines of "where the upper function corresponds to the upper sign" anyway.

Comment: Thank you J.M. for editing and helping.

Comment: @Tom I definitely recommend against using it without explanatory text. It is highly unusual. At best most readers will be held up figuring out what it means. At worst they will give up in irritation.

Comment: do you think that this explanatory is good?
> $a \pm b = {func1\atop func2}(c)$

means:

> $a+b=func1(c)$

> $a-b=func2(c)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask:

> "Is it written well, according to the laws of mathematical language?"

There aren't really laws, just guidelines. Mathematics isn't a programming language. So I agree with J.M.'s comment 100%.

But, to make the meaning of the notation a little, clearer, you might want to write something more along the lines of
$$\cot\alpha\left\{\begin{matrix}+\\-\end{matrix}\right\}\tan\alpha=\frac{2}{\left\{\begin{matrix}\sin\\\tan\end{matrix}\right\}(2\alpha)}$$

or something like that. Either way, make sure to explain in text what you mean.

Comment: $+1$ for the comment that mathematics is not a programming language.

Comment: thanks, you are defenetly right about that comment.
do you think that the explanation i gave is understandable?

Comment: The phrase "in that formula, I meant that in case of '+' we will use the sin() function, and in case of '−' we will use the cos() function" is understandable to me. The other one not so much.

Comment: but i want to have a general explanatory, which is the second one. do you think its understandable?

Comment: @Tom, to be honest, if I saw the general explanation on its own, I don't think I'd understand what it meant. Why not just use it once, explain to the reader what it means in that particular case, and then just assume that the reader gets it thereafter? Unless you're designing a genuinely formal foundations of math that you're planning to computer formalize, that's really all you need.

Comment: Ok good idea thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's not standard notation.  I would not count on a reader correctly understanding it, unless you explain it.

You could introduce it as your own special notation, but unless you feel it makes a huge difference in the clarity or conciseness of your work, I would not do so.  Readers tend to get annoyed by gratuitous use of non-standard notation.  Don't use it just to save writing one or two lines.  But if there are dozens of places in your paper where it saves duplication, then it might be worth considering.

Comment: thanks, you are right, just wondered if its understandable